# How to interpret the results of Kolmogorov-Smirnov test in SAS?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, descriptive-statistics

I'm obtaining this results ins SAS and I'm pretty sure that the **sample is normal**, but I'm unable to interpret the KS test, so I put this images and the results that I obtained from SAS in order to get help for somebody in the **KS test interpretation**.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: From the histogram, I'm 'pretty sure' the sample is not normal. In particular, the 'tails' of the data seem too short to be normal. Quantile-quantile plot seems to confirm this. Furthermore, assuming that the three tests have 'normal data' as null hypothesis, the small P-values (all below 5%) indicate that the null hypothesis should be rejected.